# Having trouble creating a weather converter program

Tags: objective-c

I started school for computer programming just a couple weeks ago and we just started Objective-C! We need to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit and Kelvin. To do that I must input the amount of Celsius. Then I use this equation to get Fahrenheit: * 9 / 5 + 32. To get Kelvin I add 273.15.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    float Celsius;
    float Farenheight = Celsius * 9 / 5 + 32;
    float Kelvin = Celsius + 273.15;

    printf("How many degrees in Celsius?");
    scanf("%s %s %d", Celsius, Farenheight, Kelvin);
    printf("C: %s, F: %s, K: %d", Celsius, Farenheight, Kelvin);

}
```

This is (the second revision of) what I came up with so far, but I am really unsure on how to do this. If anyone can help me that would be great!

Comment: It seems like your code is incompletely pasted? But, you have the formula, you probably want to use it somewhere after you get the value. What don't you get, exactly?

Comment: I agree with @zadr that it looks like your code was incompletely pasted.  Click the edit button and try again.  But from what I can see, you need to get rid of those `char` arrays and spend some time learning how `scanf` works.  You can read the input directly into the `celcius` variable without using `char` arrays.

Comment: A Tip: Take celcius, farenheight (actually, fahrenheit) and Kelvin as `float` rather than `int` as these values would be like 12.3 etc `int` won't allow you to store digits after decimal point.

Comment: I note that you've said you're learning Objective-C, but you tagged the question as C.  They're different languages, albeit that C is a subset of Objective-C.  Please be careful in your tagging; you will get inaccurate answers if you tag with the wrong language.

Comment: @zadr Yes I revised my code and added a little bit more to it! Sorry for the incomplete pasting!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I also edited the tag to make it Objective-C. I thought I did at first but I guess I never checked to see if I actually did!

Comment: Take another look at what you've now posted; then repost compilable code, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Funnily enough, temperature conversion came up in [another context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970116/how-to-print-vertically-in-c/18970323#18970323) earlier today.

Adapting that code to your outline, you need to read the value in `celsius` before you convert anything to `kelvin` or `fahrenheit` (whereas your code converts an uninitialized value, which is not a good idea):

```
double celsius;
printf("What is the temperature in degrees Celsius? ");
if (scanf("%lf", &celsius) == 1)
{
    double kelvin = celsius + 273.15;
    double fahrenheit = (celsius + 40.0) * (9.0 / 5.0) - 40.0;
    printf("%7.2f °C = %7.2f K = %7.2f °F\n", celsius, kelvin, fahrenheit);
}
```

Note that the input is checked for validity before the result is used.

The conversion formula is simpler than the usual one you see quoted, and is symmetric for converting °F to °C or vice versa, the difference being the conversion factor (9.0 / 5.0) vs (5.0 / 9.0). It relies on -40°C = -40°F. Try it:

- `C =  0°C; (C+40) = 40; (C+40)*9 = 360; (C+40)*9/5 = 72; (C+40)*9/5-40 = 32°F`.
- `F = 32°F; (F+40) = 72; (F+40)*5 = 360; (F+40)*5/9 = 40; (F+40)*5/9-40 =  0°C`.

Absolute zero is -273.15°C, 0K, -459.67°F.

Comment: +1 For such a complete and real good answer.  Though not requested by the OP, your nifty routine is a fine candidate for range qualification, typically not done enough with user I/O.  Example: `if (celsius < -273.15) then error`.  Minor: "in Celsius? " (upcase C)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code snippet to read input from stdin:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int celsius;
    printf("What is the temperature in celsius? ");
    scanf("%d", &celsius);
    printf("celsius degree = %d\n", celsius);
}
```